# changing to current directory where file.sh is located using variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I want a script that changes directory to the directory where the file.sh is located, lets say **var1**.

Then I want to copy files from another location ,lets say **var2**, to the current dir which would be **var**.

Then I want to do some unzipping and deleting rows in the files, which would be in **var**

I have tried the below, but my syntax is not correct. Can someone please advise?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Configure bash so the script will exit if a command fails.
set -e 

#var is where the script is stored
var="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd";
#another dir I want to copy from
var2 = another/directory

#cd to the directory I want to copy my files to 
cd "$var" + /PointB  

#copy from var2 to the current location
#include the subdirectories 
cp -r var2 .

# This will unzip all .zip files in this dir and all subdirectories under this one.
# -o is required to overwrite everything that is in there
find -iname '*.zip' -execdir unzip -o {} \;

#delete specific rows 1-6 and the last one from the csv file
find ./ -iname '*.csv' -exec sed -i '1,6d;$ d' '{}' ';'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in)  If a script can tell which directory it is in, changing to that directory is trivial, of course.

Comment: Don't use + to concatenate strings. Don't use spaces around the = signs.

Comment: This smells like an online exam. Notice how the 2 `find`s differ slightly in syntax? Notice how the vars are used differently in all lines?

Comment: it's not for an exam. my 2 find commands work fine as is but could possibly be written in a better/more correct way.the trouble i'm having is with the cd and cp lines

Answer (score 1):

a few mistakes here:

```
# no: var="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd";
var=$(cd "$(dirname "$0") && pwd)
```

The stuff in $() executes in a subshell, so the "pwd" must be performed in the same shell that you have "cd"-ed in.

```
# no: var2 = another/directory
var2=another/directory
```

The = cannot have whitespace around it.

```
# no: cd "$var" + /PointB  
cd "$var"/PointB
```

shell is not javascript, string contatenation does not have a separate operator

```
# no: cp -r var2 .
cp -r "$var2" .
```

Need the $ to get the variable's value.

```
# no: find -iname '*.zip' -execdir unzip -o {} \;
find . -iname '*.zip' -execdir unzip -o {} \;
```

Specify the starting directory as the first argument to find.

Comment: initially this did not work for me, I'll have another look. my first declaration was working so not sure why i need to change it. and as I said above the trouble i'm having is with the cd and cp lines.tks

Comment: You must have mis-typed your code: you have two open `$(` but only one close `)`

Comment: there is 3 `"` in the `var` declaration maybe 1 is missing?